# ViewScope variables becoming null, keepsessionalive not working?

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, xpages-ssjs, xpages-extlib

I'm having a problem with View Scope variables in Lotus Notes 9.0.1.

A user reported an error with my application, where a viewscope variables may become null on page load - the variable is an array, which the computed value of a label in a custom control tries to access, causing a runtime exception. The variable should be loaded through a library method, called by a computed title script for the accordion pane which contains the custom control that is trying to read it.

The whole thing works every time as far as i've tested, but one user of the application reported the runtime exception. Investigating further, i verified the error can be reproduced by making a build of the application and clicking some link on the open page. Reading about such problems and the server log, i learned this might be caused by a loss of scoped variables, possibly triggered by a session timeout, but our application should be able to deal with session timeouts using the keepsessionalive control from the XPages Extension Library - yet it seems not to be working as intended.

I would like some input about other possible causes/triggers for the problem (i've been unable to reproduce the problem as it was reported by the user so far), and alternatives to keep the session alive for long periods of time without the loss of scoped variables.

Here's the code:

Accordion title (where the variables are loaded, other titles are similar):

```
    viewScope.contadorParecer=carregaContadoresParecer(); //Where the variable should be loaded
    if(viewScope.contadorParecer.total>0)
    return "Pareceres ("+viewScope.contadorParecer.total+")";
    else
    return "Pareceres"

Script library method (similar code for the others):

    function carregaContadoresProposta() {
        try {
            contadoresProposta = {};
            try {
                if (arguments[0])
                    var totalizar = arguments[0];
                else
                    var totalizar = compositeData.totalizarUnidade;
            } catch (e) {
                var totalizar = false;
            }

            if (!totalizar) {
                var strView = "vw_proposta_contador";
                var filtro = sessionScope.usuarioLogado.nome;
            } else {
                var strView = "vw_proposta_unidade_contador";
                var filtro = sessionScope.usuarioLogado.fk_entidade_funcional;
            }

            //cria navegador
            var nav: NotesViewNavigator = database.getView(strView).createViewNavFromCategory(filtro);
            var entry: NotesViewEntry = nav.getFirst();
            var total = 0;
            while (entry != null) {
                var categoria = entry.getColumnValues()[1];
                categoria = @UpperCase(categoria);
                contadoresProposta[categoria] = entry.getColumnValues()[entry.getColumnValues().size() - 1];
                if (!categoria.isEmpty()) 
                total += contadoresProposta[categoria];
                var tmpentry: NotesViewEntry = nav.getNextCategory();
                entry.recycle();
                entry = tmpentry;
            }
            contadoresProposta["total"] = total;

            return contadoresProposta.clone();
        } catch (e) {
            printError(e, "carregaContadoresProposta", "Script Library ContextualProposta");
        }
    }
```

Custom control (contadorAcompanhamento, contadorProposta and contadorParecer become null before being read):

```
var label=item.split("|")[0];
label=label.indexOf("{")!=-1?label.split("{")[0]:label;

var parecer=compositeData.parecer[0];
var acompanhamento=compositeData.acompanhamento;

if(!parecer){
    if(acompanhamento){
        var total=viewScope.contadorAcompanhamento[@UpperCase(label)];
    }else{
        var total=viewScope.contadorProposta[@UpperCase(label)];
    }
}else{
    var total=viewScope.contadorParecer[@UpperCase(label)]; 
}

if(total!=undefined)
    return label+" ("+ total +")"
else
    return label;
```

The runtime error:

```
Error while executing JavaScript computed expression
Script interpreter error, line=11, col=37: 'viewScope.contadorProposta' is null and cannot be accessed as an array
```

First error found on the user's server log: (likely caused by the tmpEntry set in the scriptlibrary)
    Exception ocurred calling method NotesViewNavigator.getNextCategory()

Comment: It sounds like what the user is telling you is not the whole process and is missing key information. You don't explain what the cause was and the steps to reproduce, when you were able to get the problem. Also, is the error in the server log relevant or not? You mention `keepSessionAlive` component, but don't confirm if you or the the user is leaving the browser tab - and any other tabs for the application in the browser - inactive for a period of time. If not, session timeouts are irrelevant.

Comment: I believe the server log is not relevant. I think it's a consequence of the variables being emptied, not likely the cause, since several variables become null, and not all of them call getNextCategory to be populated. I included it tho, because i'm a bit of a beginner and figured i could be missing something.

And yes, the user has not given much information about the error other than the runtime error printed on the browser, and that the error happened while going from a tab to another (partial refresh). It's been a pain to reproduce, but it's likely the page has been inactive for a while.

Comment: " i verified the error can be reproduced by making a build of the application and clicking some link on the open page." -> Does this mean you, build the app while you are working with it ?

Comment: Yes, umeli. I am aware that this is probably not the actual cause of the problem, building the application just causes variables to be dropped left and right. I just consider it an important bit of information (and the way i'm currently using to test for the application's behaviour) because it creates the exact same runtime error screen the user saw.

Comment: My advice: stop using proprietary properties in viewScope with troublesome initialization scripts, and implement managed bean with "view" scope. That will handle all the troubles with value initialization.

Answer (score 0):

As Paul explained: you might be in for a long investigation. However the real issue you face is an unfortunate approach of using a scoped variable. Session and Application scope are subject to timeout and expiry, so never take them for granted and check for their existence. So instead of seeding the values in an unrelated location, you check for their existence in a script function.

Something along the lines (in a SSJS script library):

```
  var carregaContadoresParecer = {
      storage : null,
      total : function() {
          if (storage === null) {
             storage = populateStorage();
          }
          return storage.total;
      },
      contadorParecer : function(whatSearch) {
          if (storage === null) {
             storage = populateStorage();
          }
              // your code here
      }

  }
```

Along those lines. Then you can use `carregaContadoresParecer.total()` and `carregaContadoresParecer.contadorParecer('someLabel');`

So you wouldn't store a function in a scope, but in a JavaLib and only store values in scope and check for existence of that values. I would use a managed bean, but that because I'm comfortable with Java - might not be your thing.

Answer (score 0):

If the user has a lot of tabs open for different pages in the application, the server-side map of pages (views, thus `viewScope`) can be filled and a previously used one is dropped. This is handled in the Xsp Properties on the Persistence tab. There are various sessions slides around and it's also covered in Mastering XPages and XPages Portable Command Guide books.

It's possible that's the cause, but further information from the user will be needed to confirm or refute.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the viewScope variable "contadorProposta" initialization? Are You sure it has been initialized? The viewScope is lost when user reloads the page - is it possible?

Comment: The accordion container initializes 'contadorParecer', 'contadorProposta' and 'contadorAcompanhamento' the same way, by calling a 'carregaContadores...' function in the script library, similar to carregaContadoresProposta. All three are becoming null.

Not sure if some reload circumstance can cause the viewscope to be lost, but it should be recalculated on page load either way - i've even added a call to load the value on all three variables on the very script that reads them (i'm not entirely sure this did or not work tho - i haven't been able to reproduce the error either way)